# Having trouble deleting content from input box once enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble figuring out how to be able to delete the content in the input box once enter is hit. If you could provide information as to what code and where it belongs would be very helpful.

// Code goes here

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function (){
  $(this).toggleClass('completed');
});

$('ul').on('click', 'span', function(events){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$('input').keypress(function cleartext(event){
  if(event.which === 13) {
    var todoItem = $(this).val();
    $('ul').append(
      "<li>" +
          "<span>" +
              "<i class='fa fa-times'></i>" +
          "</span>" +
          todoItem +
      "</li>"
      );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('input').keypress(function cleartext(event){
  if(event.which === 13) {
    var todoItem = $(this).val();
     $(this).val('');//this will clear the contents
    $('ul').append(
      "<li>" +
          "<span>" +
              "<i class='fa fa-times'></i>" +
          "</span>" +
          todoItem +
      "</li>"
      );
  }
});
```